# How to passing data to modal in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I need to pass data to a modal. that modal is form to edit data.
I have make array data in the controller for passing the data to modal, but i m still confusing to passing data to the modal in codeigniter.

This is my controller :

```
public function edit($id_ekspor){
    $eks = $this->m_ekspor->GetDataEkspor("where id_ekspor = '$id_ekspor'");
    $data = array(
        "id_ekspor" => $eks[0]['id_ekspor'],
        "e_berat" => $eks[0]['e_berat'],
        "e_nilai" => $eks[0]['e_nilai'],
        "tahun" => $eks[0]['tahun'],
        "id_industri" => $eks[0]['id_industri'],
        "nm_industri" => $eks[0]['nm_industri']
    );

}
```

This is my modal :

```
<div id="con-close-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <div class="modal-dialog"> 
                    <div class="modal-content"> 
                        <div class="modal-header"> 
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> 
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Update Data Ekspor</h4> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <?php echo form_open('master_ekspor/update'); ?> 
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="field-3" class="control-label">Id Ekspor</label> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_ekspor" value="<?php echo $id_ekspor; ?>"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="field-3" class="control-label">Nama Industri</label> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nm_industri" value="<?php echo $nm_industri; ?>"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="field-3" class="control-label">Berat (Kg)</label> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="e_berat" value="<?php echo $e_berat; ?>"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                            </div>  

                        <?php echo form_close(); ?> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

How to passing that data array in controller to modal ?

Comment: your modal should be in some .php file in view folder add it to in controller

Comment: I think it would be easy if you do some javascript with that

Answer (score 0):

## Controller

```
public function edit($id_ekspor=""){
$eks = $this->m_ekspor->GetDataEkspor("where id_ekspor = '$id_ekspor'");
$this->data = array(
    "id_ekspor" =>$eks[0]['id_ekspor'],
    "e_berat" => $eks[0]['e_berat'],
    "e_nilai" => $eks[0]['e_nilai'],
    "tahun" => $eks[0]['tahun'],
    "id_industri" =>$eks[0]['id_industri'],
    "nm_industri" =>$eks[0]['nm_industri']
);
$this->load->view('users/social-activity/index1',$this->data);              
}
```

You should pass data in your controller to view like this above code